# How can I use 'react-web-vector-icons' in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use send icon from `react-web-vector-icons` but when I use it it displays box inside of icon. How can I get send icon from `react-web-vector-icons`?

If `react-web-vector-icons` doesn't work for send button can someone please suggest some package for icons ?

**Code:**

```
<div id="chat">
    <div class="card">
        <div id="messages" class="card-block">
        </div>
    </div>
    <textarea id="textarea" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter message..."></textarea>
    <Icon name='md-send' color='blue' size={20} />
</div>
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: @Ionut I don;t want button I am trying to display send icon

Comment: @Ionut I have seen the 3rd step and I have imported the icon i.e `import Icon, { FontAwesome, Feather } from 'react-web-vector-icons';` and then I am using it inside react class component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your component you should have these because `ms-send` is included in `Ionicons` :

```
import Icon, {
    Ionicons,
} from 'react-web-vector-icons';
```

next is to use Icons

```
<Ionicons
    name='md-send'
    color='blue'
    size={20}
        />
```

**For Suggestion another package** you can use [React Icons](https://github.com/react-icons/react-icons)

**Updated**
if you still can't see icons so we need to imports fonts but how. first import `font-face` in your index.html like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: AntDesign;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        src: url(fonts/AntDesign.ttf) format('truetype')
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: Entypo;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        src: url(fonts/Entypo.ttf) format('truetype')
    }
```

for complete import please see this [file](https://github.com/sturmenta/react-web-vector-icons/blob/master/test/src/index.html)

now we need to import fonts with `webpack` so in your `webpac.config.js` add these test:

```
{
            test: /\.(ttf)$/,
            use: [{
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: './fonts/[name].[ext]'
                },
            },]
        }
```

we add these to webpack to load font's , simply we can add below line instead of webpack test in `index.js` of you app :

```
require('react-web-vector-icons/fonts');
```

for complete see of `webpack` config you can see this [file](https://github.com/sturmenta/react-web-vector-icons/blob/master/test/webpack.config.js)

now we import styles and fonts in our app and means we can see the icon, restart your app because we change webpack config and refresh page.

Comment: It is not working still getting blue box instead of send icon are you sure it is `Ionicons` ?

Comment: honestly the  "React Icons" package was much easier to use and the icons are available out of the box as react components. Would def recommend over "react-web-vector-icons" if one is in a position to choose.